# Unable to map JSON response to a predefined class in C# / dynamic property name

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a class which basically contains a property like this:

```
public class Msg
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "XD1703301059485299")]
    public Shipping shipping { get; set; }
}
```

the problem is in this part:

```
 [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "XD1703301059485299")]
```

And the dynamic property name that I get from server...

This property name can be any name that server returns. In this particular case it's able to map the JSON to my class since the property names are same... But when server returns something like this:

```
XS12394124912841
```

The object is the null....

How can I resolve property name to be dynamic ? Can someone help me out?

P.S. This is the JSON response itself:

```
{"status":1,"msg":{"dynamic_name":{"order_sn":"12312313123123123","order_status":"0","shipping_info":[{"shipping_name":"","shipping_no":"","shipping_img":"","shipping_code":"","shipping_time":"","track_goods":""}]}},"errcode":0}
```

Comment: If you're using Json.Net, implement a custom converter, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base

Comment: @BurnsBA Could you help me out to write an example for this particular case of mine... ? I'm working first time with JSON like this, and I'm not really sure what to do

Comment: edited my answer if the property name can't be set at compile time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I don't think this problem is as dynamic as it sounds. You can probably just convert to a `dyanmic` object and explicitly handle conversions.

Sample solution below. I inserted a few values to show conversion works as expected.

Add nuget package Newtonsoft.Json

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;

namespace Serialize
{
    public class Shipping
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "shipping_name")]
        public String Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "shipping_img")]
        public String Img { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "shipping_code")]
        public String Code { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public Shipping shipping { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "order_sn")]
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "order_status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*
             {
             "status":1,
             "msg": {
                 "dynamic_name": {
                     "order_sn": "12312313123123123",
                     "order_status":"0",
                     "shipping_info": [{
                         "shipping_name":"name",
                         "shipping_no":"",
                         "shipping_img":"img",
                         "shipping_code":"code",
                         "shipping_time":"",
                         "track_goods":""
                     }]
                 }
             },
             "errcode":0
             }
             * */
            var raw = "{ \"status\":1, \"msg\":{\"dynamic_name\":{\"order_sn\":\"12312313123123123\",\"order_status\":\"0\",\"shipping_info\":[{\"shipping_name\":\"name\",\"shipping_no\":\"\",\"shipping_img\":\"img\",\"shipping_code\":\"code\",\"shipping_time\":\"\",\"track_goods\":\"\"}]}},\"errcode\":0}";

            var incomingOrder = new Order();

            // properties on dynamic objects are evaluated at runtime
            dynamic msgJson = JObject.Parse(raw);

            // you'll want exception handling around all of this
            var order = msgJson.msg.dynamic_name;

            // accessing properties is easy (if they exist, as these do)
            incomingOrder.SerialNumber = order.order_sn;
            incomingOrder.Status = order.order_status;

            // JObject cast might not be necessary. need to check for array elements, etc.
            // but it's simple to serialize into a known type
            incomingOrder.shipping = ((JObject)(order.shipping_info[0])).ToObject<Shipping>();

        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, if the property name is given at runtime, you can dereference properties with the indexer getter

```
        dynamic msgJson = JObject.Parse(raw);

        JObject order = msgJson.msg["XS12394124912841"];

        incomingOrder.SerialNumber = order["order_sn"].ToObject<string>();
        incomingOrder.Status = order["order_status"].ToObject<string>();
        incomingOrder.shipping = order["shipping_info"][0].ToObject<Shipping>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement something like this with the help of System.Web.Helpers

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("sample.json"))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    dynamic data = Json.Decode(json); 
    Console.WriteLine(data["your_property"]);
}
```

Here sample.json contains your sample JSON response.

Comment: Sameer, this doesn't really answers my question... Point is to map the C# class to a dynamic JSON property name. I'm sure theres a way to do this

Comment: Can you share your full JSON response?

Comment: yes sure one moment ill post it in my initial question